# Google Datastore library conflict with Apache beam DatastoreIO

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am using Google Dataflow sdk

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and Google Datastore sdk

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I got the following conflict when using  DatastoreIO.v1().write():

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreOptions$Builder.host
```

Comment: Please check the versions and make sure the dependencies are compatible

Comment: You wont need to add cloud-datastore sdk dependency.
Remove and try it again.